# Overload operator over and over

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, operator-overloading, return-by-reference

I've overloaded operator << in my own vector class that will work as follows

```
int main() {
    my_vector<int> vec;
    vec << 1 << 2 << 3;     // will add elements at end [ 1, 2, 3 ]

    display(vec);
}
```

This works perfectly fine as I want, but I wanted to make it more efficient I did this

```
    10 << vec;              // will add element at begin [ 10, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

> But this goes wrong when I do it multiple times like

```
    20 << 10 << vec;        // this does [ 20480, 1, 2, 3 ];
```

that first does operation on 20 << 10, then 20480 << vec

> I want to process it like [ 20, 10, 1, 2, 3];

Comment: `20 << 10 << vec` is `(20 << 10) << vec`. Try `20 << (10 << vec)`.

Comment: You cannot change associativity of an operator, so it's not possible to do what you want.

Comment: The `<<` and `>>` operators [are processed left-to-right](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). You can't change that as it's part of the language. Would it be acceptable to write `20 << (10 << vec);`

Comment: Rule of 3/5/0 broken in your links BTW.

Comment: @KaranPatil I'm not sure I understand, how would `20 << 10 << vec` be any more efficient than `20 << (10 << vec)`?

Comment: If `vec << 10` means push 10 into vec, then I would assume `10 << vec` means push vec into 10. But apparently you're trying to make it mean something else. Why? That just seems confusing to essentially anyone else who might ever try to read your code. (And then the consequence of trying to subvert the common meaning of things is that it doesn't quite work right.)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `20 << 10 << vec` would be more efficient if you wanna add much more times like `vec << 10 << 20 << 30 << 40` works fine and even `10 << vec << 20` works fine, but operator precedence stops me when doing `30 << 20 << 10 << vec`

Comment: @TheUndeadFish `vec << 10` pushes at the end and `10 << vec` pushes 10 at beginning of vec, so it becomes more efficient to add at beginning, even works fine but not for multiple time you can see here https://github.com/karanp0202/my_vector

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, I'm not the expert but I will look for it :)

Comment: `10 >> vec` seems more natural than `10 << vec`.

Comment: Alternative would be to have a "wrapper"/token to have something like: `mytoken >> 10 >> 20 >> vec;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, these seems the best way possible :)

Comment: I think something like `vec << addAtBeginning << 10 << 20;` would be a better approach. If I read your code I would at least have a good chance of understanding what it does.

Comment: IMO you mixed up the words "efficient" and "short".

Comment: Really I would say just keep it simple and have an `insert` function which takes two parameters: the data to insert and the position to insert it at. That's just as efficient as whatever kind of operator overload you could come up with, and is more flexible. Sometimes operator overloads aren't the best idea. For reference, take a look at `std::vector` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Comment: Another possible way, if you want to avoid parentheses, is to do something like `vec_inserter(20) << 10 << 100 << 1000 << x << y << z << vec;` This looks similar to string concatenation to me, so isn't too far fetched. `vec_inserter` would return a proxy object that collects the elements to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential solution is to create a proxy object, or even a full-fledged vector object, that aggregates the elements to be inserted.

The interface would look approximately like:

```
vec_front_inserter(20) >> 10 >> my_vec;
```

Note that I recommend using the extraction operator (`>>`) to indicate front-insertion, as it reads better to me, but feel free to change back to the insertion operator (`<<`) if you don't like this.

Your implementation would require:

1. Define an `operator>>(const my_vector&, my_vector&)` to represent front-inserting one vector into another.
2. Create a  proxy `vec_front_inserter` class that has `operator>>(vec_front_inserter&, int)` defined, and holds a `my_vector` internally.
3. Define a `operator>>(const vec_front_inserter&, my_vector&)` to insert the elements at the front of `my_vector`.

```
class vec_front_inserter {
public:
    vec_front_inserter() {}
    vec_front_inserter(int seed) {
        _data.push_front(seed);
    }

    friend vec_front_inserter& operator>>(vec_front_inserter& proxy, int value);
    friend my_vector& operator>>(const vec_front_inserter& proxy, my_vector& vec);

private:
    my_vector _data;

};

vec_front_inserter& operator>>(vec_front_inserter& proxy, int value) {
    _data.push_back(value);
}

my_vector& operator>>(const vec_front_inserter& proxy, my_vector& vec) {
    vec.insert_front(proxy._data);
}
```

This feels similar to me to string concatenation.

You can do something like:

```
std::string concat = std::string("foo") + "bar" + "biz" + "baz";
```

But you can't do something like:

```
std::string fail = "foo" + "bar" + "biz" + "baz";
```

Answer (score 1):

### Side note:

Please do not overload operators in ways which is not expected. This will be confusing and will make hard to read/maintain your code.
I can't imagine such overload in professional code, but it could be done just for fun.

### On topic

Now you second approach didn't works since operators: `<<` `>>` have left-to-right associativity. This means that when you write:

```cpp
vec << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

this is equivalent to:

```cpp
(((vec << 1) << 2) << 3);
```

and when you write:

```cpp
20 << 10 << vec;
```

actual outcome is:

```cpp
((20 << 10) << vec);
```

So it calculating `20 << 10` first and result of that is feed to your overloaded version of operator `<<`.

In theory you could overload other operators with have right-to-left associativity (for example `<<=`, `>>=`), to achieve your goal, but as I point out this is very bad practice and this would make it even worse.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of operator precedence/associativity. The compiler first performs the << operation between `20` and `10`, and then performs another << operation between the result and `vec`. That's because if you have more than a single `<<` operator, they will be processed from left to right.

Using parenthesis should solve it:

```cpp
20 << (10 << vec);
```

This tells the compiler to first perform the operation between `10` and `vec` and then perform another operation between the result and `20`.

(Assuming you implemented the operator overloading correctly).

Comment: @KaranPatil: You didn't ask question in your question. so people might imagine you don't know the associativity of this operator.